# Create table in yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. Can anyone teach me how to transform below table into Yii scripting format?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Stages</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Stage 1</th>
        <td>data from db</td>
        <td>data from db</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Stage 2</th>
        <td>data from db</td>
        <td>data from db</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
       <th>Stage 3</th>
       <td>data from db</td>
       <td>data from db</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To Yii GridView you assign data and columns, Yii makes everything else

Comment: You can use GridView for yii

Comment: I don't know how to create table with the first row and first column are defined static. Is there any sample I can refer to?

Comment: You can do it using Yii gridview, rest of all things will be handle by Yii. Ref. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/381/cgridview-clistview-and-cactivedataprovider/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CGridView` to transform table into Yii scripting format.
See below code.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'stages-grid',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'table',
    'summaryCssClass'=>'panel-body',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'stages',
            'header'=> 'Stages',
            'value' => $model->stages,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'stages1',
            'header'=> 'Stages 1',
            'value' => $model->stages1,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'stages2',
            'header'=> 'Stages 2',
            'value' => $model->stages2,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'stages3',
            'header'=> 'Stages 3',
            'value' => $model->stages3,
        ),

    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

use [**CArrayDataProvider**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) and [**CGridView**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

```
echo CHtml::openTag('table');
echo CHtml::openTag('tr');
...
echo CHtml::closeTag('tr');
echo CHtml::closeTag('table');
```